# Why does my discord bot ignore awaitMessages?

Tags: javascript, node.js

i tried using await message to store words in an array and then send them to discord. Here's the bot code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const {prefix, token} = require('./config.json');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once("ready", (message) => {  
    console.log("Bot is online!");
    client.user.setActivity("Komnata", {type: "WATCHING"});
})

client.on("message", async message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}role`)) {
        await message.delete();
        const filter = m => {m.author.id === message.author.id};
        message.reply("Choose embed title (message will expire after 10 seconds").then(r => r.delete(10000));
        message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {max: 1, time: 10000}).then(collected => {
            var newArray = []
            newArray.push(collected);
            message.channel.send(newArray[0])         

        }).catch(err =>{
            message.reply("Time has expired!").then(r => r.delete(3000));
        })
    }

})
client.login(token);
```

When i send a message to the channel(which contains one word), the bot completely ignores it and i get an error in the console:

```
Bot is online!
(node:3228) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
    at item.request.gen.end (c:\Users\Adam\Desktop\botd\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\rest\RequestHandlers\Sequential.js:85:15)
    at then (c:\Users\Adam\Desktop\botd\node_modules\snekfetch\src\index.js:215:21)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:3228) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:3228) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: You have 3 promises without catch blocks (.reply and .send). Have you caught those errors and inspected their content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: i had to leave out the curly brackets on the filter